# How do I get a Plesk 11 server to accept email to addresses with delimiter (VERP)?

Tags: email, plesk, verp

### What I Want

We send out bulk renewal notices via email and it would be ideal if we could link any bounce messages with the corresponding record in our database. I recently learned about [VERP](http://www.postfix.org/VERP_README.html) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path)) and thought that would be the perfect solution for us.

### What I Tried

I did a test before making any changes and the message is bounced back to sender, as expected. Then I uncommented this line in /etc/postfix/main.cf and restarted Postfix.

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

### The Problem

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. Messages sent to addresses that include the delimiter are no longer rejected, but they don't appear to be delivered anywhere either. Here's an excerpt from the maillog:

```
Jul  8 12:14:36 cl-t082-392cl postfix/smtpd[28723]: 6E98A1A404CC: client=mta02.eastlink.ca[24.224.136.13]
Jul  8 12:14:36 cl-t082-392cl postfix/cleanup[28727]: 6E98A1A404CC: message-id=<6.1.2.0.2.20130708131351.24958960@pop.eastlink.ca>
Jul  8 12:14:36 cl-t082-392cl postfix/qmgr[28717]: 6E98A1A404CC: from=<me@example.com>, size=1343, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  8 12:14:36 cl-t082-392cl postfix/pipe[28752]: 6E98A1A404CC: to=<bounces+test@ourdomain.com>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.22, delays=0.15/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Jul  8 12:14:36 cl-t082-392cl postfix/qmgr[28717]: 6E98A1A404CC: removed
```

So it appears that Postifx is doing its job, but that the `plesk_virtual` service is dropping the ball. No message is returned to sender. No message shows up in bounces/Maildir/cur. If `plesk_virtual` is writing an error somewhere, I don't know where (I checked /var/log/messages).

### My Search Efforts

I searched Google, here, and the Parallels forums. I got several hits in Google for the same problem I am having, but they are all for the same message which is dated almost 3 years ago. And there was no solution given. I posted to the Parallels forums several days ago. I've gotten a few views, but zero responses.

### What I *Don't* Want

I've seen similar problems where the suggestion was to forward all undelivered mail to a particular address. That's a catch-all. And that is not a realistic solution in today's world of spam.

### Question

How do I get Plesk to correctly recognize and deliver messages to addresses with the delimiter? I can't imagine that I am the only one who wants to do this on a Plesk server.

Comment: Apparently, I *am* the only one who wants to do this on Plesk. I've been researching for more than a week now, and the only answer I got was that plesk_virtual does not support it. I've finally given up. I'm going to try the catch-all approach. I've set up a separate domain just for sending email from the database. Hopefully, the spam volume will be manageable.

Comment: This could (and IMHO should) be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I answered this on the Plesk forums. For anyone still interested there is a postfix workaround. 
Added the following to the main.cf:

```
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map
```

Created a file /etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map with this regex:

```
/^(.+)\+.+@(.*)/ ${1}@${2}
```

Granted, it assumes + is the only VERP delimiter but it works. The only caveat is that it does not bounce bad addresses, which may not be a bad thing..

Comment: So what happens to mail addressed to bad addresses? Silently discarded?

Comment: What happens to mail addressed to non-VERP addresses? If I am reading the regexp correctly, this requires a `+` in the address.

Comment: Also, this is not reliable long term because updates will overwrite config files. There are two related Plesk feature requests: https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4177476-have-an-option-to-deliver-email-addressed-to-verp and https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4156106-allow-customization-of-etc-postfix-main-cf